# CSS How to add content under fixed position navbar

Tags: css, navigation, navbar

I have a fixed position navigation bar.
The height the navbar is 50px

I want to put some text under the navbar, but I don't know how.

Comment: show us your markup

Comment: Check out my solution!

Comment: Provide your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this line in your css flie:

```
body { padding-top: 50px; }
```

or:

```
.some-text { padding-top: 50px; }
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
.navbar {
  position: fixed;
  height:50px;
  width:100%;
  background: #333;
}
.contents-under {
  padding-top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
  Your Navbar
</div>
<div class="contents-under">
  some contents under navbar
</div>
```